# DOMElement output empty html string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to bring back a **DOMElement** to a string so that I can make some manipulation to the string.
But when I use this code :

```
$('#formular .hexaflip-cube>div').each(function(index, div)
{
    console.log(div)
    console.log($(div).html())
    // Now we check every field inside a div
    $('input[type!="hidden"]', div).each(function(index, input) {
        console.log(input)
    });
});
```

The html output is not working properly in some cases for some reason.
I tried to use the **innerHTML** attribute of the element directly but same problem.

Here is what I got with this code :

[image]

Does anyone have an idea of what's wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you use `find` instead

```
$(div).find('input[type!="hidden"]').each(function(index, input) {
        console.log(input)
});
```

Comment: the problem is that I need also the complete div string because I have to assign it to a var for an external library

Comment: Well no, if you like at the image you can see that the problem is that the third div is not recognized properly by jQuery